# Homework: Comparing intermediate expressions with == in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written the code below to test whether a list is a Palindrome or not. To my surprise its not compiling with the error  "No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of == ....". My assumption is that the compiler does not know that `leftHalf` and `rightHalf` are lists.

```
    isPalindrome :: [a] -> Bool
    isPalindrome [] = False
    isPalindrome xs = if (leftHalf == reverse rightHalf)
              then True
              else False
     where leftHalf = take center xs
           rightHalf = drop center xs
           center = if  even (length xs)
                       then (length xs) `div` 2
                   else ((length xs) - 1) `div` 2
```

1) How do I tell the compiler that `leftHalf` and `rightHalf` are lists? 
2) How would I use pattern matching or other haskell language features to solve this? 
EDIT: Thank you all for your input. Special mention to Matt Fenwick for the documentation link and Duri for the elegant tip. I will write the final solutions below just in case

```
     isPalindrome' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
     isPalindrome' [] = False
     isPalindrome' xs = if p then True else False
                   where p = leftHalf == rightHalf
                         leftHalf = take c xs
                         rightHalf = take c (reverse xs)
                         c = div l 2
                         l = length xs
```

`isPalindrome'` can be improved like Demi pointed out

```
      isPalindrome'' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
      isPalindrome'' [] = False
      isPalindrome'' xs = if (reverse xs) == xs then True else False
```

Comment: Just think about what `xs` and `reverse xs` look like for every palindrome and your code will be much simpler.

Comment: btw this code is wrong (after getting it to compile):  `map isPalindrome [[1], [1,2,1]]` is `[False, False]`.

Comment: The `div` will round down, so the `even` test is unnecessary.  Just divide the odd number by 2, and you'll get the same answer.  However, as @Matt points out, your algorithm doesn't work when the length is odd, since you don't want the center element in either the left *or* the right half.  The `take` needs to round down, and the `drop` needs to round up.

Comment: Note that your definition of `center` is the same as `center = div (length xs) 2`.

Comment: Note that your use of `take` and `drop` can be replaced by `splitAt`.  (Of course, to make your function work you need to change your `take` and `drop` calls.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `Eq` typeclass:

```
ghci> :i (==)
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
    -- Defined in GHC.Classes
infix 4 ==
```

What you need is [a type constraint](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101) on `isPalindrome`.

Also, this code

```
if (leftHalf == reverse rightHalf)
              then True
              else False
```

is unnecessarily long.

Comment: Thanks your response has been very insightful.

Answer (score 4):

In order to test if two lists are equal, it must be possible to test if the items in the list are equal.  Therefore, your list of type `[a]` must ensure that `a` is an instance of `Eq`.

Also, as a matter of style:

```
x = if c then True else False
```

can be replaced with

```
x = c
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your type to:

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

And this is really extraneous to find center, it's enough to just write `xs == reverse xs` - when you computing `length xs` you go through all the list and there is no economy.